# How to find chained sequences of tasks using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Let's suppose we have these 3 Dataframes with 'Start' & 'End' Dates of a certain task.

```
Task1 = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=10**3, freq="1H")}).assign(
    End=lambda d: d.Start + pd.Timedelta(hours=20))

Task2 = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("10-jan-2021", periods=500, freq="3H")}).assign(
    End=lambda d: d.Start + pd.Timedelta(hours=24))

Task3 = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("5-jan-2021", periods=700, freq="2H")}).assign(
    End=lambda d: d.Start + pd.Timedelta(hours=16))

durations = [20,24,16]
names = ['Task1', 'Task2', 'Task3']
nbr_of_tasks = 3
```

I'm looking for a way to link each 'End Date' of task[x] with 'Start Date' of task[x+1] etc...
For the time being, I'm able to find only the sequences where Task_x['End'] == Task_x+1['Start'] where x is the task number. The following code is what I came up with :

```
list_dfs = [Task1,Task2,Task3]
rev_list_dfs = list(reversed(list_dfs))
comparaison_dates = list(rev_list_dfs[0]['Start'])
rev_list_dfs = rev_list_dfs[1:len(rev_list_dfs)]
print(comparaison_dates)

for element in rev_list_dfs:     
    inception = element.loc[element['End'].isin(comparaison_dates)].reset_index(drop=True)
    if inception.empty :
        print('No available slots for the chosen interval')        
        break
    else :
        comparaison_dates = inception['Start']

miccheck = []
for element in names:
    miccheck.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=[f'{element}_Start', f'{element}_End'])) 

for i in range(0,nbr_of_tasks):
    miccheck[i][f'{names[i]}_Start'] = comparaison_dates + pd.to_timedelta(sum(durations[:i]), unit='h')
    miccheck[i][f'{names[i]}_End'] = comparaison_dates + pd.to_timedelta(sum(durations[:i+1]), unit='h')
    

excell = pd.concat(miccheck, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
print('\n       Start & end date of each sequence       \n')
print(excell)
```

How can I find the succession of tasks where there is a downtime between each one? By downtime I mean the amount of waiting hours before we can execute the next task. I'm not specially looking for a made up answer, just pointing me in the right direction would be helpful. Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

Desired output :
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some sample of the desired output?

Comment: My desired output is similar to the 'excell' dataframe in my script. What I wish to add is a column between pair of tasks mentionning the number of 'Stand-by' hours or 'Downtime'. In my case, they all have 0 hours between them, so I'm skipping sequences where i.e we finish Task_1 & wait few hours then start Task_2 (Task2['Start Date'] - Task1['End Date'] != 0)

Comment: @KeyserSoze in the OP please

Comment: Thanks for replying @TimStack & Danail Petrov , I just added the desired output in the post however it doesn't contain the sequences with 'Stand-by' > 0, contrary to what I really want

Comment: Can multiple rows in Task1 be linked to the same row in Task2? Or needs there to be a 1:1 assignment? If this is not required, `pd.merge_asof` should work.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Anton, indeed multiple rows in Task1 can be linked to one row from Task2 as long as Task1['End Date'] < Task2['Start Date']. I'm searching for all the possible combinations with a 'Stand-by' != 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key idea is to use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). For two task dataframes the following would find for each row in `Task1` the row in `Task2` where `End_1` and `Start_2` are closest to each other (but still `End_1 <= Start_2`):

```py
pd.merge_asof(
    Task1.rename(columns=lambda c: c + "_1"),
    Task2.rename(columns=lambda c: c + "_2"), 
    left_on="End_1", 
    right_on="Start_2", 
    direction="forward",
)
```

The following function applie this idea to an arbitrary number of task dataframes and also computes the stand-by time:

```py
def merge_task_dfs(dfs):
    dfs = [df.rename(columns=lambda c: c + f"_{i+1}") for i, df in enumerate(dfs)]
    
    output = dfs[0]
    
    for i, df in enumerate(dfs[1:]):
        i += 1
        output = pd.merge_asof(
            output,
            df,
            left_on=f"End_{i}",
            right_on=f"Start_{i+1}",
            direction="forward",
        ).assign(**{f"StandBy_{i}_{i+1}": lambda d: d[f"Start_{i+1}"] - d[f"End_{i}"]})
        
    return output
```

It can be applied to the provided example data as follows:

```py
Task1 = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=10**3, freq="1H")}).assign(
    End=lambda d: d.Start + pd.Timedelta(hours=20))

Task2 = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("10-jan-2021", periods=500, freq="3H")}).assign(
    End=lambda d: d.Start + pd.Timedelta(hours=24))

Task3 = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("5-jan-2021", periods=700, freq="2H")}).assign(
    End=lambda d: d.Start + pd.Timedelta(hours=16))

df = merge([Task1, Task2, Task3])
```

The first 5 rows of the output are:
[image]